# Currents in short circuit wires connected in parallel

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWKzno.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There were two inductors at **I1** and **I2** which at steady state became short-circuited. What would be their currents? I am confused as to how the currents distribute in presence of two shorted wires?

Comment: If these are real world inductors then they will have some resistance. In which case the current (15/(1000+L1¦¦L2)) will divide in inverse ratio to their individual resistances. Otherwise , if this is purely theoretical and they offer zero resistance, then I guess you could say that the 15mA will divide equally.

Comment: All, some, or nothing.  Watch this: https://www.youtube.com/live/ySuUZEjARPY?si=Ov3g5AWkyYzSQB36&t=1965 ("How to Achieve Proper Grounding - Rick Hartley - Expert Live Training (US)")

Answer (score 3):

15 V and 1 kΩ define a total current of 15 mA. That's all you can say given the information in that ideal schematic, I1 + I2 = 15 mA.

If you had more information, like the residual resistance of the inductors, and the wires leading to them, then you could enter those onto the schematic, and determine how the current splits.

Bear in mind exactly what a schematic is, and isn't, telling you.

- It is telling you that I1 and I2 are connected in parallel.
- It is telling you that whoever drew the schematic is disregarding any resistance that real world inductors and wires might have as insignificant compared to what they want to model.
- It is not telling you that I2 is going through a longer path so carries less of the share of current, those lines only show connectivity, not hint at anything parametric.

Answer (score 0):

If you have supra-conductor inductors and supra-conductor wires, then there is no way to know how the current will split between I1 and I2.

If not, then your inductors have some internal resistance (the "simplest" model of an inductor you can use for this is an ideal inductor in series with a resistor), and your wires also have some resistance (probably much smaller than the one of the inductors).

So now, you have one (or 2 if you count the wires) small resistors (expect something in the 0.1-50 ohms range depending on your inductors) on each branch : you know have a classical current divider you should be able to solve yourself (if not, ask for additional help after explaining where exactly you are stuck)